# How can I split a section of the page in three parts?

Tags: tables

I'm working on the LaTex paper and turns out I'm using three small tables that I want to fit in just a portion of the page, I don't want to divide the whole page. This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

And I want them to be placed all in a horizontal row and this is my code so far.

```latex
\noindent
\textbf{Escriba las tablas de verdad de una compuerta OR, AND y XOR.}

% compuerta OR

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Compuerta OR}
\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

% compuerta AND

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Compuerta AND}
\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 0               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

% compuerta XOR

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Compuerta XOR}
\label{tab3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 0               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: You should  see the `floatrow` package.

Comment: Please provide a code by which is produced showed result. It scan be be inserted in three mini pages in one line or in table with three columns.

Comment: done, code added!!!

Answer (score 1):

- You not provide about used document class not of page layout ...
- using `article` with default page layout and mini pages gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption} % <---


\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Escriba las tablas de verdad de una compuerta OR, AND y XOR.}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta OR}
\label{tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta AND}
\label{tab2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 0               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta XOR}
\label{tab3}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
0          & 0          & 0               \\ \hline
0          & 1          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 0          & 1               \\ \hline
1          & 1          & 0               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
you may like the following design of true tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{Escriba las tablas de verdad de una compuerta OR, AND y XOR.}

    \begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta OR}
\label{tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = { c c|c },
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                 } 
A   & B & Output    \\ 
    \hline
0   & 0 & 0         \\
0   & 1 & 1         \\
1   & 0 & 1         \\
1   & 1 & 1         \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta AND}
\label{tab2}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = { c c|c },
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                 }
A   & B & Output    \\
    \hline
0   & 0 & 0         \\
0   & 1 & 0         \\
1   & 0 & 0         \\
1   & 1 & 1         \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Compuerta XOR}
\label{tab3}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = { c c|c },
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
                 }
A   & B & Output    \\
    \hline
0   & 0 & 0         \\
0   & 1 & 1         \\
1   & 0 & 1         \\
1   & 1 & 0         \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this worked just finee, thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with the `floatrow`  package and its eponymous environment:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \textbf{Escriba las tablas de verdad de una compuerta OR, AND y XOR.}

    % compuerta OR
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \centering
    \ttabbox{\caption{Compuerta OR}\label{tab1}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    % compuerta AND
    \ttabbox{\caption{Compuerta AND}\label{tab2}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    %
    \ttabbox{\caption{Compuerta XOR}\label{tab3}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{Output} \\ \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}

    \end{floatrow}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ups, instead to edit my answer I do this in your s. Sorry. Addendum is now deleted/moved to my answer..

Comment: @Zarko: This also happened to me once. No problem!

Comment: Thankkks so much!! :)

Comment: You"re welcome. Always glad when I can help!